# error express-handlebars@7.0.1 when deploying nodejs app to render

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars

i'm trying to deploy my nodejs app with express handlebars to render but i keep getting this error

```
error express-handlebars@7.0.1: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=v16". Got "14.17.0"
Mar 8 04:40:12 PM  error Found incompatible module.
Mar 8 04:40:12 PM  info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
Mar 8 04:40:12 PM  ==> Build failed 
Mar 8 04:40:12 PM  ==> Generating container image from build. This may take a few minutes...
```

please how i can i go about this

Comment: Did you read https://render.com/docs/node-version?

Answer (score 0):

"engines": {"node": ">=18.16.0"}

add this is in your package.json